# Linux notifies when process starts

Tags: linux, unix, process

Trying to find a way to be notified when a process is started on linux. The problem is that a process A kicks off process B and process B dies after kicking off process C. I need to keep a track of the process ids of A,B and C. Process history is not maintained for dead processes.

Comment: For occasional use strace(1) might suffice.

Comment: Explain much more what are *A*, *B*, and *C*. Do you have their source code? Are they free software? Can you configure them (e.g. replace some of them with a wrapping shell script)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to get a notification when a process start, you just want to track processes that belong to specific group reliably. Well, Linux has a great facility for that - use [Control Groups](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt). You can read more about control groups [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch01.html).

Move process A into a control group of its own, all subsequent children of it and its children will belong to that control group by default and since the list of PIDs of processes belonging to a control group can be queried you can use it to track these processes.

Using cgruoups in this way has additional benefits as well - such as the ability to track and even limit the resources (CPU time, IO bandwidth etc.) used by this process group, the ability to freeze and restart the group as a whole and more.

CGroups happens to be the mechanism that HTCondor, the distributed batch job management system, uses to accomplish the same task, so there is a lot material available on this subject that is HTcondor related. See for example this [section in the HTCondor manual](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/current/3_12Setting_Up.html#SECTION0041212000000000000000) and this [wiki post](https://htcondor-wiki.cs.wisc.edu/index.cgi/wiki?p=HowToLimitMemoryUsage).

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You may want [process accounting](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Process-Accounting/), e.g. [GNU acct](http://www.gnu.org/software/acct/). But that probably would deal with most of your processes.

If you can change, configure, or adapt your *A*, *B*, or *C* consider using [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html). That could be as simple as replacing program *B* with e.g. a script starting with [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) and then `exec`-ing the original *B* program. You could even try to play tricks with your `PATH` to do that "transparently".